# Add controller drivers post-installation in windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers

i got an old desktop pc with windows xp. Now the IDE-controller died and I installed an pci-ide-controller and I connected the old hdd to the new controller.
Is it possible to copy the driver files (*.cat, *.inf, *.sys) in a folder that I can boot from this card?

Have I only to copy these files to c:/Windows/System32/drivers or have I to do some further things?

I know there are solutions (nlite) to add this driver to my installation iso but i would prefer to use the old installation of windows xp.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not nearly that straight-forward.

HDD controller drivers are (usually) kernel-level, and as such the kernel needs to be aware of them (and where they are) so that it knows which files to load.

Same reason you need to hit F6 and give 3rd party drivers *before* XP's setup gets beyond the actual loading phase (from CD).

Perhaps boot an XP disk, give it the controller's F6 drivers (if required), and hopefully it will recognize the existing Windows install, and allow you to do an "[in-place upgrade](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978788)".